# All-Pass Filter Magnitude Computations

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, filters

I've got an exercise on Fourier Transform. I have to show that the following is an all-pass filter: I have to show that $|\hat h(\omega)|=1$ where

$$
\hat h(\omega)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^K\dfrac{\bar a_k - e^{-i\omega}}{1-a_ke^{-i\omega}}
$$

with $a_k\in\mathbb{C}$ $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$. My idea was to bound that quantity from above and from below with some expressions and show that being bounded $1\le |\hat h(\omega)| \le 1$ it is equal to one, but could not find a nice way to obtain this. Any other idea or hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is much easier to obtain than any bounds. From properties of complex numbers and their magnitudes we get that

$$|\hat{h}(\omega)| = \left|\prod_{k=0}^K \frac{\bar{a}_k-e^{-i\omega}}{1-a_ke^{-i\omega}}\right| = \prod_{k=0}^K|e^{i\omega}|\cdot\left| \frac{\bar{a}_k-e^{-i\omega}}{a_k-e^{i\omega}}\right| = \prod_{k=0}^K 1 \cdot 1 = 1$$

using $|e^{i\omega}| = 1$ and $|\bar{z}| = |z|$ since the numerator is the conjugate of the denominator.